# In Scala 2.13+, how can one efficiently implement a conversion to a particular standard collection type?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

The current collection framework favors the use of `to` method in order to convert to the target collection type, and with an implicit conversion available from various collection companion objects to the `Factory` argument, this creates a neat, uniform interface. It unfortunately makes very hard optimisations which were easy in the old framework with `CanBuildFrom`. Lets say I have a custom collection type `Unique[T]`, which is a combination of `Set` and `Seq` in that the order in which elements follows the order of insertion, but any element can occur only once. Because it offers fast `indexOf`, `apply(i :Int)` and `contains`, conversions to both `Set` and `Seq` can be `O(1)` with a simple wrapper. I can override `toSet` and `toSeq`, but I see no way of determining inside `to` (other than extremely questionable reflection) that the target factory builds `Seq` or `Set`, because the `Factory` implementation used by the implicit conversion is generic and not a prototype instance like old `ReusableCBF`.

Comment: Can you elaborate why you can't provide multiple `Factory` implementations? I.e. specialised implementations for `Factory[Unique,Seq]` and `Factory[Unique,Set]`?

Comment: `Factory` doesn't take two collection types as type parameters like `CanBuildFrom` did: Its signature is `Factory[E, C]`.  Code  `xs to Set` resolves to `xs to Set.iterableFactory`, i.e. the generic default `Factory` implementation which calls `Set.from(xs)`. I cannot thus influence the `Factory` used statically by providing an implicit value (and it wouldn't be polymorphic in any way), and the only way to recognise that a `Factory[E, C]` is a `Factory[E, Set[E]]` is `f.getClass == Set.iterableFactory.getClass && outer.get(f) == Set`, where outer is a reflected *synthetic* `Field`.